# system error! on binary upload on Samung Seller Portal

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-build, android-buildconfig

I am trying to upload an APK file on Samsung Seller Portal as an update to already existing app. I built the app using "Generate Signed Bundle/APK" option on Android Studio. I am getting "system error" after the apk file is uploaded, what are the probable reasons for this error? The upload worked on Google play store.

Comment: Were you able to fix it? How did you do it? Thanks.